# What does the prototype of a user-defined object do?

Tags: javascript

```
// Create an object type UserException  
function UserException (message){  
  this.message=message;  
  this.name="UserException";  
}  

// Make the exception convert to a pretty string when used as  
// a string (e.g. by the error console)  
UserException.prototype.toString = function (){  
  return this.name + ': "' + this.message + '"';  
}
```

I don't understand why you need the `UserException.prototype` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prototype` is applied on objects which are created through the `new` operator, like this:

```
var user_exception = new UserException("Error");
```

So, now all of the properties and methods which were stored in the `prototype` is now accessible on the `user_exception` object:

```
alert(user_exception); //alerts UserException: Error
```

In the following statement:

```
throw new UserException("Value too high!");
```

1) It constructs a new `UserException` object, passing in the "Value too high!" string

2) That new object gets handed off to `throw`, which expects an object with the `.toString()` method defined on them, which will then get output to the console's `error` log.

Comment: Wait, so where is UserException.prototype.toString() used here? `throw new UserException("Value too high");`

Comment: @DarkLightA `.toString()` is implicitly called when that object is concatenated or printed out.

Answer (score 3):

Every "UserException" object will automatically share that "toString" function this way. You *could* assign that function in the constructor:

```
function UserException(message) {
  // whatever
  this.toString = function() { /* ... */ };
}
```

but now each instantiation will also instantiate a new distinct function object for the "toString".

Comment: Wow! That makes perfect sense, and seems to make JS so much more powerful in my eyes.

Comment: @DarkLightA: Maybe should read about prototype inheritance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Comment: Wait, so where is UserException.prototype.toString() used here? `throw new UserException("Value too high");`

Comment: See my comment below. It's probably implicitly called when the error is 'alert'ed or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not you'd use `UserException` as a singleton or not.

When you use `.prototype` every instance of `var foo = new UserException` has its own copy of `this.toString`, which will be scoped to that object.

You generally don't assign functions in the constructor, because each instance will get a copy of that function made for it in memory. Prototyping it on to the actual object definition keeps it in one spot (afaik) that is referenced by each object.

Comment: Wait, so where is UserException.prototype.toString() used here? `throw new UserException("Value too high");`

Comment: .toString is a native JS function that can be called implicitly in a number of ways (concating two strings together, trying to 'print' an object by alerting it, logging it, etc)